# How to set Varnish so that it doesn't cache URL

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I need export csv from url: http://domain.com/nextopia/products/csv/key/5213ae8cdcb0270226dc816e3838eac0

after waiting I get the error time out:

error 503 service unavailable service unavailable varnish

I have tried:

```
if (req.http.host == "domain.com" && req.url == "/nextopia/") {
    return (pass);
}
```

and:

```
if (req.url ~ "^/nextopia/") {
  return (pass);
}
```

and:

```
.first_byte_timeout = 600s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
```

but not effective, how to export it??!! :(

Answer (score 1):

The ~ is matching so you only need to match something with the url, like:

```
if (req.url ~ "/nextopia") {
    return (pass);
}
```

Without using the regex roof.
Also req.url == "/nextopia/" is match of exact /nextopia/ so /nextopia wont match..

Have you check your logs to see if there some error like timeouts and/or other errors? Cheers